# Facebook App Token to Page Token without logged-in user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

Having an application token, a user who authorized the application with manage_pages permission, how can I access to the pages this particular user is admin of?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, you need a user access token for that permission as outlined in the docs

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/  (look for accounts)

Comment: user already gave manage_pages permission, if I get another user access token, then is the application token useless?

Comment: My point is, you can only query that stuff for the current logged in user, as such you need to use the user access_token not the app access token as it is data related to a specific user

Answer (score 0):

You don t need an application token but a user access token to access those pages

Comment: User already gave permission, we do not want to bother the user again.

Comment: What do you mean by bother the user again? Every time the user logs in using your application, you get an access_token. Use that access_token to query graph api and get his facebook accounts(Pages + Applications) and from there extract the pages.